# doctrine 2 mapping - many to many thows exception when trying to persist owning side

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, sqlexception

I'm new to doctrine and I got stuck. Any help will be appreciated.
I created two entities: Task and Group with a many to many relation with group being the owning side. I tried to persist them. Task gets persisted, but group trows an SQL exception.

Here is the code for **Task.php**:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

/**
 * Task
 */
class Task
{
/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $task;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 */
private $dueDate;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
private $groups;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->groups = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set task
 *
 * @param string $task
 *
 * @return Task
 */
public function setTask($task)
{
    $this->task = $task;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get task
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTask()
{
    return $this->task;
}

/**
 * Set dueDate
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dueDate
 *
 * @return Task
 */
public function setDueDate($dueDate)
{
    $this->dueDate = $dueDate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dueDate
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDueDate()
{
    return $this->dueDate;
}

/**
 * Add group
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Group $group
 *
 * @return Task
 */
public function addGroup(\AppBundle\Entity\Group $group)
{
    $this->groups[] = $group;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove group
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Group $group
 */
public function removeGroup(\AppBundle\Entity\Group $group)
{
    $this->groups->removeElement($group);
}

/**
 * Get groups
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getGroups()
{
    return $this->groups;
}
}
```

**Task mapping**

```
AppBundle\Entity\Task:
  type: entity
  table: task
  id:
   id:
     type: integer
     generator: { strategy: AUTO }
  fields:
    task:
      type: string
      length: 256
    dueDate:
      type: date
   manyToMany:
    groups:
      targetEntity: Group
       mappedBy: tasks
```

**Group.php**

```
    <?php

    namespace AppBundle\Entity;

    /**
     * Group
     */
    class Group
    {
        /**
         * @var integer
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var string
         */
        private $name;


        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return integer
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * Set name
         *
         * @param string $name
         *
         * @return Group
         */
        public function setName($name)
        {
            $this->name = $name;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get name
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getName()
        {
            return $this->name;
        }
        /**
         * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
         */
        private $tasks;

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->tasks = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        }

        /**
         * Add task
         *
         * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Task $task
         *
         * @return Group
         */
        public function addTask(\AppBundle\Entity\Task $task)
        {
            $this->tasks[] = $task;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Add tasks
         *
         * @param array
         *
         * @return Group
         */
        public function addTasks(array $tasks)
        {
            foreach ($tasks as $task) {
                if (is_a($task, 'AppBundle\Entity\Task')) {
                    $this->tasks[] = $task;
                }
            }
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Remove task
         *
         * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Task $task
         */
        public function removeTask(\AppBundle\Entity\Task $task)
        {
            $this->tasks->removeElement($task);
        }

        /**
         * Get tasks
         *
         * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
         */
        public function getTasks()
        {
            return $this->tasks;
        }
    }
```

**Group mapping**

```
 AppBundle\Entity\Group:
      type: entity
      table: group
      id:
        id:
          type: integer
          generator: { strategy: AUTO }
      fields:
        name:
          type: string
      manyToMany:
        tasks:
          targetEntity: Task
          inversedBy: groups
          cascade: ['persist', 'remove']
```

**The controller**

```
class DoctrineController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function setupAction()
    {
        $group = new Group();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $tasks = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Task')->findAll();
        $group->setName('personal');
        $group->addTasks($tasks);
        $em->persist($group);
        $em->flush();

        echo 'success';

        return $this->render('AppBundle:Doctrine:setup.html.twig', array(
        ));
    }
}
```

**The exception:**

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO group (name) VALUES (?)' with params ["personal"]:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group (name) VALUES ('personal')' at line 1
```

I think it has to do with table constraints, but I don't know how to fix it. I'm pretty sure there's a flaw in my logic. If anyone can point me into the right direction with a quick-fix and an explanation/link to an article as to why this works like it does, I'll be very grateful.

Comment: You are using a reserved word as a table name `group` and since doctrine isn't escaping the name you get that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Symfony documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#add-mapping-information

> Be careful that your class name and properties aren't mapped to a
>   protected SQL keyword (such as group or user). For example, if your
>   entity class name is Group, then, by default, your table name will be
>   group, which will cause an SQL error in some engines. See Doctrine's
>   Reserved SQL keywords documentation on how to properly escape these
>   names. Alternatively, if you're free to choose your database schema,
>   simply map to a different table name or column name. See Doctrine's
>   Creating Classes for the Database and Property Mapping documentation.

Check the Doctrine documentation for advice on how to quote these reserved words: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words

But after all it is adviced to not use reserved words in your class or class attribute names.

Comment: Thank you very much, that one went over my head. It feels like I stubbed my toe just as I was walking in.